# How to persist data in a command-line application?

Tags: node.js, go, authentication, terminal, command-line-interface

I want to build a command-line application using Go or Node.js. I want to make it multiuser, so a login feature is needed. I can implement the login feature but I don't understand where should I store the user data which can be fetched any moment at runtime.
The user data is needed to check if a user is logged in or not if he is logged in which user it is.

Need help with a method to store user data to check logged in status

Edit:
I had thought of this- If the config file is present that the user is logged in else not. Then I realized that if one tampers the file, the whole point of login feature will get invalid. I am guessing there must be a better way to do it, which I am trying to know by asking here

Comment: I think question isn't conveying what I want to ask. I am editing the question

Comment: There are many ways to persist data. Common options include: Using a ready-made database, storing data in a file, or using a remote server.

Comment: You can set an environment variable. That ensures it only persists for the current shell session

Comment: Why are you worried about end-users tampering with a config file on disk manually? If you store a checksum alongside the data, you can be slightly more confident that it hasn't been tampered with. For more confidence, likely you will need to introduce some remote authority to the mix.

Comment: For inspiration, you can have a look at how the Google Cloud SDK (`gcloud` command) does it. It stores its state under the `$HOME/.config/gcloud` directory by default. It seems to contain files in arbitrary formats, YAML, and also some sqlite databases. (Obviously the fact that this program implements it as such does not in any way imply this is a "good" strategy. As always: "it depends").

Answer (score 3):

Many cli utilities opt to store their configuration as a plain text file on the user's home directory.
You can use any of the available configuration formats such as JSON, TOML, etc.

Although it's good to mention that this is not a secure way of storing data and if users should not be able to see others information in any way this is **not** the preferred way.

Comment: I had thought of this. If the config file is present that the user is logged in else not. Then I realized that if one tampers the file, the whole point of login feature will get invalid.
I am guessing there must be a better way to do it, which I am trying to know by asking here